# WP CLI unknown parameters

Tags: wordpress, parameters, command-line-interface

I've copied the following command from the docs:

`wp post delete $(wp post list --post_type='page' --format=ids)`

but am getting this error:

```
Error: Parameter errors:
 unknown --post_type parameter
 unknown --format parameter
```

Can someone please explain why? Also, what is the `format=ids` part supposed to do anyway? I just want to delete all pages.

Comment: Hmm no answers, I have this same issue...

Answer (score -2):

I got this to work by changing shells to PowerShell.  If you use PowerShell **(C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe)** instead of the command prompt **(C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe)** it seems to work.

I use this in conjunctions with Visual Code, so if you want some instructions on how to change the default shell with Visual Code [look here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal).